# IntelliJ IDEA - Remote Development - Backend IDE was not started successfully

Tags: intellij-idea, ssh, jetbrains-ide, jetbrains-toolbox, remote-development

I had this error today after updating my **IntelliJ IDEA** on Windows machine and trying to access project on my remote Ubuntu virtual machine over SSH with **JetBrains Gateway**.

- JetBrains Client 2022.1
- JetBrains Gateway 2022.1
- IntelliJ IDEA 2022.1 (Ultimate Edition)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### TL/DR

I've removed whole `/home/user/.cache/JetBrain`s folder.

### Explanation

I've resolved my problem by checking logs:

> #c.i.i.StartupUtil - JVM options: [-Djava.home=/home/user/.cache/JetBrains/RemoteDev-IU/...
>
> Line 86164: 2022-04-25 09:40:57,760 [    288]   INFO - STDOUT - This
> IDE build has expired. Please download a new build from JetBrains
> official site

Since it was remote project on my Ubuntu 20.04 virtual machine.

I've removed whole `/home/user/.cache/JetBrain`s folder.

Next time I started my remote project from JetBrains Gateway it downloaded client and other missing files automatically on my Ubuntu machine and then everything worked.

For some reason IDE on Ubuntu side didn't get updated when opening remote project on Ubuntu.

Comment: throw in a `pgrep -f jetbrains` and `kill -9 <PID>` for each number you see, for good measure. works well

Comment: Take @stapmoshun solution. No need to delete any cache folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try switching your login shell on the server to bash.